# Get an hour of time period between given minimum and maximum time period

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `time_period`,

```
CREATE TABLE `time_period` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` time NOT NULL,
  `slots` int(11) NOT NULL
) ;
```

The data in the table is basically time period in a 24 hour clock at the interval of 5 minutes. Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `time_period` (`id`, `time`, `slots`) VALUES
(1, '00:00:00', 3),
(2, '00:05:00', 3),
(3, '00:10:00', 3),
(289, '24:00:00', 3);
```

Live test: http://rextester.com/live/UXPV82172

What I am trying to achieve is, get an hour of time between min_time and max_time (I am concatenating same date as date given in min_time and max_time) ,given that the current_time (actual current date and time).

### EDIT: updated the greater than less than sign, had an error here there (sorry)

```
SELECT 
    t0_.id AS id_0, 
    t0_.time AS time_1, 
    t0_.slots AS slots_2 
FROM time_period t0_ WHERE 
    '2018-03-18' + t0_.time >= '2018-03-18 19:09' AND # :min_time
    '2018-03-18' + t0_.time <= '2018-03-18 20:09' AND # :max_time
    '2018-03-18' + t0_.time >= '2018-03-17 21:05' # :current_time
    ORDER BY t0_.time ASC LIMIT 20
```

Looked pretty straight forward but for some reason all I get is:

> `1,00:00:00, 3`

### EDIT

Expected output must be same as when running sql:

```
SELECT 
t0_.id AS id_0, 
t0_.time AS time_1, 
t0_.slots AS slots_2 
FROM time_period t0_ WHERE 
t0_.time >= '19:09:00' AND
t0_.time <= '20:09:00';
```

i.e.

> `1    245 19:10:00    3`
>
> `2    246 19:15:00    3`
>
> `3    247 19:20:00    3`... and so on

Could someone help me explain this please.

Comment: what should the output look like?

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: Clearly this expression isn't doing what you intended: '2018-03-18' + t0_.time Take a look at the edits I made in rextester. Don't you really just need to use date/time functions to add/subtract an hour. It's not clearly where your values are coming from so that's hard to say.

Comment: Indeed, apparently I just had to concatenate two fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I just had to concatenate my date and time field to get datetime field for comparison.

```
SELECT 
    t0_.id AS id_0, 
    t0_.time AS time_1, 
    t0_.slots AS slots_2,
    concat('2018-03-18', " ", t0_.time) as x
FROM time_period t0_ WHERE 
    concat('2018-03-18', " ", t0_.time) >= '2018-03-18 19:09:00'
    AND
    concat('2018-03-18', " ", t0_.time) <= '2018-03-18 20:09:00'
    AND
    concat('2018-03-18', " ", t0_.time) >= '2018-03-17 21:05'        
    ORDER BY t0_.time ASC LIMIT 50
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to build them into datetimes if you want to compare them.

```
   CONVERT(DATE, '2018-03-18') +    
   t0_.time >= CONVERT(DATETIME, 
   '2018-03-18 19:09') AND # :min_time
   #etc
```